# Error when making calculations with Decimal?

Tags: smartcontracts, scrypto

When I try to calculate the fee of something, it wont work. For example if I try:

```
let foo: Decimal = 100.0 * 1.0
```

I get this error: `expected Decimal, found f64`

I've tried: `let foo: Decimal = 100.0.into() * 10.0.into();` - still doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decimal is a Scrypto type. You can only calculate Decimal with other Decimal types in Scrypt, in this case, you do:

```
let foo: Decimal = Decimal::from("100.0") * Decimal::from("10.0");
```